# Why does nautilus show different permission icons on lost+found in an external drive?

Tags: linux, permissions, nautilus

On my external drive, I have an ext4-formatted partition.
I've recently noticed that the icon that's shown in the file manager on the `lost+found` directory there is different from the one shown for the one in my root directory. In `/`, it's a cross, and in the drive, it's a lock. I've checked using `ll`, and the mode, owner and group are the same. Why is this?

Interestingly, when increasing the scale of the icons, the external drive's folder's icon includes a cross symbol, just like in `/`, *alongside* the cross.

Output of `ll`:

```
$ ll /
total 72K
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Oct 22 20:03 bin -> usr/bin/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Jan 22 02:33 boot/
drwxr-xr-x  22 root root 4.8K Jan 23 08:00 dev/
drwxr-xr-x 146 root root  12K Jan 24 15:44 etc/
drwxr-xr-x   4 root root 4.0K Dec 25 23:39 home/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    7 Oct 22 20:03 lib -> usr/lib/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    9 Oct 22 20:03 lib32 -> usr/lib32/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    9 Oct 22 20:03 lib64 -> usr/lib64/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root   10 Oct 22 20:03 libx32 -> usr/libx32/
drwx------   2 root root  16K Dec 25 23:25 lost+found/
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4.0K Dec 25 23:39 media/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Oct 22 20:03 mnt/
drwxr-xr-x   7 root root 4.0K Jan 18 02:07 opt/
dr-xr-xr-x 390 root root    0 Jan 23 02:14 proc/
drwx------   6 root root 4.0K Jan  1  1970 recovery/
drwx------   7 root root 4.0K Dec 27 21:45 root/
drwxr-xr-x  33 root root  940 Jan 24 14:44 run/
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    8 Oct 22 20:03 sbin -> usr/sbin/
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Oct 22 20:03 srv/
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Jan 23 02:14 sys/
drwxrwxrwt  29 root root 4.0K Jan 24 17:04 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x  14 root root 4.0K Oct 22 20:03 usr/
drwxr-xr-x  13 root root 4.0K Dec 26 02:18 var/
$
$ ll "/media/anselmschueler/Data (ext4)/"
total 56K
drwxrwxr-x 4 anselmschueler anselmschueler 4.0K Jan 23 00:48 Archive/
drwx------ 2 root           root            48K Jan 24 14:47 lost+found/
drwxrwxr-x 3 anselmschueler anselmschueler 4.0K Jan 23 03:34 Videos/
```

[image: Nautilus on external drive]
[image: Nautilus on root directory]
[image: Scale increased on icons on external drive]

My system is running Pop!_OS 20.10

Comment: What filesystems are you using on the two disks?

Comment: I'm using ext4 on both.